# "After Nth" in series, is it N+1?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I am not sure if somebody already asked this question but I am wondering when I say: **I made a hit (song) after 3 songs.**  or **It wasn't interesting to me anymore after the third message**

Does it mean, that

> A. My hit song was the 3rd song I made and Third message was no longer interesting to me

or

> B. My hit song was the 4th song I made and Fourth message was no longer interesting to me

Comment: Neither **A** nor **B** is correct. When you use the _preposition phrase_ to say _"It wasn't interesting to me anymore **after the third message**"_, you are saying that the third message is the last one that was interesting. When you say _"I made a hit **after three songs**"_, you are saying that the fourth song was a hit.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth song was the first hit and the fourth message was the first without interest.

The key word here is "after".  It was after the three songs and after the third message that things happened.

This can be very ambiguous. If you said "I had a hit song after three attempts.", it would be the third song which was the hit because it is the one that was had after three attempts.